# EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available

Tags: java, wildfly, jndi, ejb-3.1

i am doing migration from jboss 5 to wildfly 12.
i got stuck in one of my exceptions
i am doing ejb (3.1) invocation using wildfly 12 with jndi in java 8
i have deployed .ear file on the wildfly console
after that i am getting this exception.
i am using java ee 5.

This is for a Wildfly 12 server, java 8. I have tried changes in jndi properties.

```
private final Properties config;

config = new Properties();

config.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNP_NAMING_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
config.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
config.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080/");
//config.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote+http://127.0.0.1:8080");
config.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");

config.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true"); 
config.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "wixxxxxx");
config.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxxxxx123");

Context ctx = new InitialContext(config);
```

I expect the output of migration and running the project successfully, but the actual output is

```
org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:567)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
    at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:172)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:569)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:503)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:913)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:177)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:112)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getServerInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.verizon.delphi.hyperion.cli.CommLine$Info.cmdProc(CommLine.java:741)
    at tcl.lang.Parser.evalObjv(Parser.java)
    at tcl.lang.Parser.eval2(Parser.java)
    at tcl.lang.Interp.eval(Interp.java)
    at tcl.lang.Interp.eval(Interp.java)
    at com.verizon.delphi.hyperion.cli.CommLine.startInterpreter(CommLine.java:5638)
    at com.verizon.delphi.hyperion.cli.App.main(App.java:133)
    Suppressed: org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: org.jboss.remoting3.ServiceOpenException: Unknown service name@http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080
        at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver$1.lambda$handleDone$0(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:83)
        at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture$NotifierRunnable.run(AbstractIoFuture.java:720)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Failed to get sys infoEJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available
```

Comment: Is it remote EJB that you are trying to connect? The error message says you do not have anything running on 8080 to connect to.

Comment: hi
yes i am trying to connect remote ejb. 
i have successfully deployed .ear file on the wildfly console and when i start the wildfly server it shows the below line in the logs---------------------------
  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: This article might help you https://www.baeldung.com/wildfly-ejb-jndi

Comment: I have already made the changes using this article but still i am getting this exception. Please Help me out.

Comment: When i deploy the .ear file on wildfly console i am not getting the jndi namespaces logs
java:global/EJBWildFly-1.0-SNAPSHOT/TextProcessorBean!com.gct.interfaces.TextProcessorRemote
 java:app/EJBWildFly-1.0-SNAPSHOT/TextProcessorBean!com.gct.interfaces.TextProcessorRemote
 java:module/TextProcessorBean!com.gct.interfaces.TextProcessorRemote
 java:jboss/exported/EJBWildFly-1.0-SNAPSHOT/TextProcessorBean!com.gct.interfaces.TextProcessorRemote
 java:global/EJBWildFly-1.0-SNAPSHOT/TextProcessorBean
 java:app/EJBWildFly-1.0-SNAPSHOT/TextProcessorBean
 java:module/TextProcessorBean

Comment: Do you have the required class and interface with right annotations?

Comment: This is my code looks like 

@Remote(MyRemote.class) @Stateless @RolesAllowed("user") public class MyAdminBean implements MyRemote, MyLocal {}@Remote public interface MyRemote extends MyAdminImpl{}@Local public interface MyLocal extends MyAdminImpl{}

Comment: I would try and deploy the remote ejb example from the quickstarts, so you know your server setup works, then compare their code to yours. Remember it might he the classpath that's the issue rather than the code. It's best to use the ejb BOM in your POM

Comment: Hello @David, Im ín the same situation, could you connect from cliente to server JNDI?

Answer (score 0):

You're initial context factory may be wrong, you don't show the value for that, but the name of that constant implies is still the only jnp protocol

Comment: Actually, we are migrating the application from jboss 5 to wildfly 12 and in line config.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNP_NAMING_CONTEXT_FACTORY); the JNP_NAMING_CONTEXT_FACTORY is just a variable and the value of JNP_NAMING_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory";

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `org.jboss.ejb.client.naming`, the connection is usually defined in a file named `jboss-ejb-client.properties`. You provided it in the map for `jndi.properties`. The `jboss-ejb-client.properties` looks like this:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connection.two.host=localhost
remote.connection.two.port = 8080
remote.connection.two.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

If this works, but you don't want to use a file for the connection-properties, you may take a look on https://developer.jboss.org/thread/202008

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is not the InitialContext Configuration, it seems correct.

Try the lookup with this format:

```
ctx.lookup("ejb:EJBWildFly-1.0-SNAPSHOT/TextProcessorBean!com.gct.interfaces.TextProcessorRemote");
```

Format is:

```
context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);
```

Check this documentation example for more information:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI